# Best way to bind multiple RHEL 6 Systems to AD and use NFS?

Tags: linux, active-directory, permissions, redhat, winbind

I am currently migrating systems to an AD domain using winbind. This works fine but I have discovered that NFS mounts don't have proper permissions because users and groups end up with different uid/gid on each system.

My question is, what would be the best way to bind these systems to AD while keeping uid/gid uniform across all systems?

Comment: Look at the "Deterministic userid/groupid mapping" section at the bottom of this page, [Winbind authentication against active directory](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WinbindADS).

Comment: I didn't have the time today to post this as an answer below. Feel free to self post an answer and accept it. This will give you the points and help any future visitors to the site without sending them to a 3rd party URL.

Comment: in every sistem do you have idmap uid and idmap gid with same values?